# Can a 'blank space' ability be replaced?

Tags: world-of-final-fantasy

In the majority of the Mirage Boards there is usually at least one node called "Blank Space".

This allows you to choose what ability you want by using a 'Seed' (of which there are various types).

If I use a seed, am I stuck with what I choose permanently? Or can they be changed/upgraded as I get better seeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, according to [this guide](http://www.novacrystallis.com/2016/10/world-final-fantasy-woff-beginner-guide/), you can change abilities set in the Blank Space.

> If you should change your mind down the road, know that you can erase and replace any ability set in the Blank Space. No sweat.

However, based on [this post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168651-world-of-final-fantasy/74474930), it's worth noting that you won't get that seed back.

> you can always change it, but you lose out on the seed forever.

(removed the specific seed mentioned in the original post)